# set-cookie header in response but not setting in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs, cookies

I am trying to implement a login page using ajax (jquery / angularjs) I am able to see the following in response headers using chrome-debug-toolbar

```
Set-Cookie:csrftoken=roaniD6RmDrzmd0X3rSkvIRvw2PYVRjm; expires=Thu, 02-Jul-2015 06:49:48 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/
Set-Cookie:sessionid=lns8nm8q24zgtsc6h1pupa3x4xbanf2r; expires=Thu, 17-Jul-2014 06:49:48 GMT; httponly; Max-Age=1209600; Path=/
```

But these cookies are not getting set in the browser.
What should I do to set these or make these recieved cookies automatically set using `angularjs` or `jquery`

Answer (score 0):

You have probably left a new line between this headers and previous ones making them not correctly parsed. Use [WebScarab](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_WebScarab_Project) proxy to inspect raw response header.

Comment: These cookies are set by a server page called by an Ajax request?

Comment: I am using django authenitication framework in the backend which is working fine.

Comment: What browser are you using? Which version?

Comment: chromium 34 on ubuntu

Comment: It looks like the problem shown at http://askubuntu.com/questions/41679/google-chrome-does-not-keep-cookies